# NumberAnimation on x don't work in ColumLayout?

Tags: qt, animation, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I want to animate text on SplashScreen but it don't work but this qml animation work but animation on scale works

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
Page{
    id:splashPage
    Component.onCompleted: {
        txtAnimation.start();
    }
    ColumnLayout{
        id:clm
        anchors.fill: parent
        Image {
            id: icon
            source: "/images/icon.png"
            Layout.preferredHeight: 200
            Layout.preferredWidth: 200
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            Layout.topMargin: (clm.implicitHeight-icon.height)/2
        }
        Text{
            id:txt
            text: "Title under application icon" 
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignTop
        }
        Item {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
    }
    SequentialAnimation{
        id:txtAnimation
        NumberAnimation {
            target: txt
            duration: 1000
            easing.type: Easing.OutElastic
            properties: "x"
            from: -1000
        }
        SequentialAnimation {
            loops: Animation.Infinite
            alwaysRunToEnd: true
            PauseAnimation{
                duration: 600
            }
            PropertyAnimation {
                target: txt
                property: "scale"
                to: 1.0
                duration: 100
            }
            PropertyAnimation {
                target: txt
                property: "scale"
                to: 0.85
                duration: 400
            }
            PropertyAnimation {
                target: txt
                property: "scale"
                to: 1
                duration: 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I change the NumberAnimation to below it works But in ColumnLayout it don't have x property

```
        NumberAnimation {
            target: txt
            duration: 1000
            easing.type: Easing.OutElastic
            properties: "x"
            from: -1000
            to:25
        }
```

I changed the code like below but it don't work too

```
        Text{
            id:txt
            text: "Title"
            color: "#7f0000"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignTop
            Behavior on x{
                NumberAnimation {
                    duration: 1000
                    //                    easing.type: Easing.OutElastic
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does this mean: *"But in ColumnLayout it don't have x property"*

Comment: in ColumnLayout I didn't set the x property so it will be itselef in center and bottom of image so I shold only set from property of NumberAnimation

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your animation works when you set the `to` property, but doesn't work without it shows us that it's necessary in this case. So you just need to set it to a value that keeps the text centered horizontally. For that, try this:

```
    to: (clm.width - txt.width) / 2
```

Comment: I don't think setting x property in ColumnLayout is a correct way.It must be a better way . may be i have done somthing wrong in my code

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code the way that it is. And it's possible that there are other ways to make this work, but that doesn't make my answer incorrect.

Comment: @JarMan is right, you need to set the `to` property otherwise there is no range defined in which the animation interpolates the value. The only way to not define `to` is if the `NumberAnimation` is defined within a `Transition` or `Behavior`. In that case `to` defaults to something defined in `Transition`/`Behavior`. Have a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-numberanimation.html#to-prop